# not able to change image in UIImageView control

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview

This seems to me as a bug because I have changed images with:

```
someImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"anotherImage.png"];
```

and I have never had a problem. so let me show you what I have:

I have placed an UIImageView:

[image]

note that imgObjetivos is conected to this UIImageView.

I have a method that get's called when clicking the following button:
[image]

and the method contains:

[image]

as you can see I just want to change the current image with:

[image]

so when I run the application in the simulator everything looks great:

[image]

and when I press the button the image changes successfully:

[image]

Now why is it that when I run the application on my iPad the image does not change!? when I press the button the image disappears instead of getting a new image like in the simulator. I just learned objective-c and I am starting to dislike it. What am I doing wrong?

---

EDIT

I found a solution I changed the name of the image and now it works:
[image]

but this makes no sense. Which names works and which ones do not? I also have make sure that I don't have two images with the same name and that is not the case. when I have a few letters after the '_' underscore it does not work. This is really strange. I am starting to dislike objective-c :(

Comment: when I have _h.png it does not work don't ask me why... I use the h for horizontal. but I guess I will change all of my names in order to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to rename the image name to something else I don't understand why... I thought that the problem was because I previously deleted that image that contained the same name but that is not the case because I imported the image with a similar name to the solution and I had the same problem. for example the original name of the image was objetivosFoto_h.png   and when I renamed to objetivosFoto_ho.png it still did not work but when I renamed to objetivosFoto_horizontal.png it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem before. The problem is that the image that you're using to replace the previous image is corrupted or say is not in it's original format.

In my case, I downloaded images in the web which was .jpg format and renamed it as .png format which actually made it .png. so in short term, ipad does not support the functionality for converting image format by just renaming the extension. you have to have a proper converter or something.

Comment: thanks a lot! I did the same without realizing it and spent so much time debugging why my CATransition animation for my UIImageView doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

I would go with removing the image file from the project, clean the project and add the file back.

Comment: Tried that but it does not work don't know why. I had to change the name. at least it works so its OK. But it is strange because even if I import it with a similar but different name it does not work.